# How do I create a Code Snippet in MS Teams using a Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-teams, code, snippets

In MS Teams, it is common to need to share code snippets quickly. Is there a keyboard shortcut that displays the code snippet editor?

[image: IMG:]

Comment: There is no shortcut - and you can't customise them either. Try an autohotkey script.

Answer (score 11):

Use 3 consecutive backticks ```` ``` ````, on the latest MS Teams versions, seems we need a space after these backticks to make it work like ```` ``` ````

Examples:

- ```` ``` ````
- ```` ```python ````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Triple backticks creates a monospaced paragraph, not a code snippet as is asked in the question.

Comment: triple backticks followed by an optional language name and a space do create code snippets.
Just tested it now ( 2023-09-13 )

Comment: doesn't for me `1.6.00.34263` on mac

Comment: can you change a setting somewhere so you don't need the add the space? it's really annoying and when I paste code from somewhere else it won't convert the ``` to a code snippet

Answer (score 1):

NB! Following information is only to those people in the world, who use keyboard layouts with **dead keys**. If you don't have such, then don't read and rate this answer and move on.

I was struggling getting the monospace text box in Teams for years and I ended up in this topic and that's why I'm provising the information for similar people. When backtick is a dead key on your keyboard (Finnish/Swedish/Estonian for example), then you need three backticks (shift+tick - tick is between question mark and backspace key) followed by TWO spaces (the big key in the middle of lower row between Alt and AltGr keys). So you basically need 5 keypresses:

1. Shift + ´`
2. Shift + ´`
3. Shift + ´`
4. Spacebar
5. Spacebar

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).